# Conflicting interpretation of an angle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

This Figure is from an exercise to calculate the height of [Blair Cuspid](https://mysteriousuniverse.org/2016/02/the-blair-cuspids-a-legitimate-lunar-anomaly/) #5.

I seem to obtain conflicting interpretations from the given condition.  In particular, I am not sure it is which angle the description

> the ground sloped downward $6.9^\circ$ in the direction of this shadow

is referring to.  My gut feeling was it refers to $\angle DBE$.  However, Question a) claims that $\angle CDB = 4^\circ$.  But shouldn't $\angle CDB = 6.9^\circ$, as the alternate interior angle of $\angle DBE$?  The only sensible explanation is that the angle measured $6.9^\circ$ is actually $\angle BDE$, but then I can not make sense of the description quoted above (English is my second language).

I Googled about Blair Cuspids and found a [research article](http://carlotto.us/newfrontiersinscience/Papers/v01n02c/v01n02c.pdf) that included some calculation.  On page 33, it goes:

[image]

The only way for me to make sense of this text is to interpret "effective elevation angle" as $\angle CDB$, and "local slope" as $\angle BDE$.  (Otherwise, I would infer conflict again.)  But I cannot get my head around these interpretations.

Am I missing some background knowledge, such as **effective elevation angle** and **local slope**?  But Google did not return anything quite useful.

Comment: I wish I hadn't clicked on the link to that website (https://mysteriousuniverse.org/2016/02/the-blair-cuspids-a-legitimate-lunar-anomaly/): it seemed to do a hell of a lot of things to my computer without asking permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to me either. Maybe it’s a mistake: for the information given, I would conclude that angle $\angle BDE$ is $4^\circ.$